# Mercurial: How do you undo changes?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

When using Mercurial, how do you undo all changes in the working directory since the last commit? It seems like this would be a simple thing, but it's escaping me.

For example, let's say I have 4 commits. Then, I make some changes to my code. Then I decide that my changes are bad and I just want to go back to the state of the code at my last commit. So, I think I should do:

```
hg update 4
```

with 4 being the revision # of my latest commit. But, Mercurial doesn't change any of the files in my working directory. Why not?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846643/mercurial-discard-local-changes-of-a-file-or-group-of-files-or-all

Answer (score 99, accepted):

[`hg revert`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revert) will do the trick.

It will revert you to the last commit.

`--all` will revert all files.

See the link for the Man Page description of it.

`hg update` is usually used to refresh your working directory after you pull from a different repo or swap branches. `hg up myawesomebranch`. It also can be used to revert to a specific version.  `hg up -r 12`.

Comment: When i did this , i can see .orig files for each files i have reverted when i check with hg status . How to  deal with this ?

Answer (score 21):

An alternative solution to `hg revert` is `hg update -C`. You can discard your local changes and update to some revision using this single command.

I usually prefer typing `hg up -C` because it's shorter than `hg revert --all --no-backup` :)

Answer (score 6):

`hg revert` is your friend:

```
hg revert --all
```

`hg update` merges your changes to your current working copy with the target revision. Merging the latest revision with your changed files (=current working copy) results in the same changes that you already have, i.e., it does nothing :-)

If you want to read up on Mercurial, I'd recommend the very awesome tutorial [Hg Init](http://hginit.com/).

Comment: pableu: you're exactly right about how `hg update` works when you have changes in your working copy: it merges them into the target revision. When you are already at that target revision, nothing happens. I edited the answer to say this in a more confident way.

Answer (score 3):

```
hg revert --all
```

and then

```
hg pull -u
```

works for me