# Mercurial discard local changes of a file or group of files or all

Tags: mercurial

From [Mercurial FAQ](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.I_did_an_hg_revert_and_my_working_directory_still_has_changes_in_it.21) page I read how to discard all local changes of my repo.

```
hg update -C -r
```

But what I want is to discard local changes in particular file and/or a group of files separated by space/comma. I tried following command but why this is not working?

```
hg update relative/path/to/my/file.rb
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `revert`

```
hg revert --no-backup file.rb
```

As of Mercurial 2.0, you can use

```
hg revert -C file.rb
```

to prevent the creation of *.orig* files.

Comment: what does -C mean here?

Comment: I think it means 'clean'. It does the same as '--no-backup' and saves you some typing.

Comment: Actually i only tried `hg revert "File Name"` and it created .orig file, now i am looking for solution to remove .orig file. Trying `hg remove "File Name with .orig"` extension is not removing the file.

Comment: Just delete the .orig file.