# Mercurial HG - How to clean repo from uncomm­itted files and stay in the current changeset?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using Mercurial ("HG"), I am trying to Clean the repo from uncomm­itted Changes using :

```
hg update --clean -R rpeo_path
```

It will Clean The repo and move to tip ( it will change the changeset )

How can i Clean the repo from uncomm­itted changes and stay in the current Changeset ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial: How do you undo changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214035/mercurial-how-do-you-undo-changes)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is probably to use [`hg revert --all`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revert).

> With no revision specified, revert the specified files or directories
>   to the contents they had in the parent of the working directory. This
>   restores the contents of files to an unmodified state...

The `--all` option will

> revert all changes when no arguments given

Answer (score 0):

I solved :

```
current_changeset = hg id -i
hg update --clean -R repo_path -r current_changeset
```

Please keep me updated if you have another opinion