# Reverting several commits and rolling back

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

The image shows that I was working **after** revision 323 when I realized that revisions 323 and 322 were completely garbage.

So, I updated to revision 321 and I now realize that this is perfect and I would like to start fresh **from here**.

Without using `strip`, is there a clean way of destroying revisions 322 and 323 and then working and building on top of revision 321?

[image]

Comment: why don't you want to use strip? have you pushed these changes already?

Comment: Exactly! I have pushed...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mercurial: How do you undo changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214035/mercurial-how-do-you-undo-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you already have pushed these changes, (which is why you don't want to use `strip`)

**Option 1**

Just commit on top of 321, after you have done that, update to 323 and close the branch. Then update back to where you were and keep working.

**Option 2**

use backout on 323, then 322, then continue committing.

**Otherwise**

If you haven't pushed, and there is some other reason you don't want to use `strip`, you could just change the `phase` of 322 + 323 to `secret`, and continue working off 321. That way they won't ever be pushed, and so never seen by anyone else.

Comment: Option 1 may generate a warning later on about pushing multiple heads, since the head to be closed was already pushed?

Comment: yes, although it's easy enough to to force the push anyway. I guess the bigger danger on reops with large numbers or uses, it that other people keep working on 323+. But hopefully closing the head, would be a big enough hint...

Comment: After closing it you can also merge it back into the other head.